# At what rate do these common definitions converge to the constant $e=2.718...$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, exponential-function

$e=2.718\ldots$ is often defined to be $$\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+1/n)^n$$ (from continuously compounded interest) and $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}$$ (from Taylor series). My question is, what are the respective rates of convergence for each of these? For example, is the error from $e$ in $O(\frac{1}{n})$? Or is the number of digits of accuracy in $O(n)$? If it's not too involved, a basic overview of a proof would also be appreciated.

And just for bonus points, since I'm curious, what is the state-of-the-art algorithm for calculating digits of $e$?

Comment: This is a cool question actually. I thought about this before where x is some irrational number. Of course you can “cheat” with the convergence algorithm, by making a single iteration of a new algorithm simply be two iterations if the previous algorithm. I remember doing some research online and finding some amazingly fast algorithms for computing pi. Like clash fast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first case,
\begin{align*}
\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n
   &= \exp \left[n \log \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)\right]
    = \exp \left[1 - \frac{1}{2n} + O\left(n^{-2}\right)\right]
    = e - \frac{e}{2n} + O(n^{-2})
\end{align*}
as $n\to\infty$. In the second case,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k \leq n} \frac{1}{k!} - e
   = \sum_{k > n} \frac{1}{k!} 
   &= \sum_{k > 0} \frac{1}{(k + n)!}
   \leq \sum_{k > 0} \frac{1}{n^k\, n!}
   = \frac{1}{n!(n-1)}
   = O\left(\frac{1}{n!}\right)
\end{align*}

Comment: So as a corollary, it's safe to say that, the limit expression has an error of $O(\frac{1}{n})$, and the number of digits of accuracy that the series gives you is $O(n \log n)$ (due to Stirling's approximation), yeah?

Comment: @chausies: Sure.

Answer (score 5):

The Laurent series expansion of $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ about the point $n = \infty$ gives you an idea of the error

$$
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = e - \frac{e}{2n} + \frac{11e}{24n^2} - \frac{7e}{16n^3} + O\left( \frac{1}{n^4} \right)
$$

On the other hand

$$
\sum_{r = 1}^n \frac{1}{r!} = e + O\left(\frac{1}{n!}\right)
$$

Hence clearly the summation converges faster than the limit.

**Example**: For $n = 10$, the limit is $2.59374...,$ whereas the sum is $2.71828...$.